# Excel Number Input restrictions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that I have cells that I want to restrict entry to be either a whole number, or a half number.

Allow  say  `5`  or  `5.5`  or `9.5`.

NOT allow  say `3.2` or  `5.7`.

I'd like to do this with a formula, not a macro.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it via data validation.

1. Select the cell in which you want to restrict the input and click on Data > Data Validation
2. Select 'Custom' from the drop down and in the formula field, you use the formula:

   ```
   =MOD(A1,0.5)=0
   ```

This basically means that cell A1 will accept values where the remainder when A1 is divided by 0.5 is 0 (i.e. it is a multiple of 0.5).

If a user tries to put an invalid value, a warning will pop up and warn that that value is not accepted. You can customize the message.

Comment: This is a good answer and correct. The only issue you may run into is if you want to disallow negative numbers.

Comment: @Raystafarian Indeed, but since nothing was mentioned about those in the question, and negative numbers are whole numbers too! In any case,  that can be fixed (should negatives be rejected as well) with `AND()` and `A1>0`.

Comment: What about a range of cells? One possibility is to enter `=MOD(A1,0.5)=0` into the first cell, and then copy and paste special selecting data validation only into other cells. But what I was hoping for was a self reference variable - something like `=MOD(value, 0.5)=0`

Comment: @Paul Unfortunately, that's not possible as far as I'm aware. You'll have to copy/paste instead.